# Getting all comments of multiple users from a certain subreddit - Reddit Dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get all the comments of every single redditor who commented in a particular subreddit, for instance r/gaming.
I know how to query for subreddits:

```
SELECT * FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2007]
WHERE subreddit = "gaming"
```

but my SQL/ BigQuery knowledge is too limited to get all comments of the redditors, who commented in a subreddit.

I was thinking something like

```
SELECT author FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2007]
WHERE subreddit = "gaming"
```

but that just gives me the author names of the users who commented in r/gaming.

**How can I search for the authors of one particular subreddit and get all their submissions across all subreddits?** 
[Here is the link to the used BigQuery-table.](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2007)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT * FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2007]
WHERE author IN (
  SELECT author FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2007]
  WHERE subreddit = "gaming"
  GROUP BY 1
)
```

Comment: That seems to work, thank you! On what does **GROUP BY 1** group the dataset? Would be cool if it would be sorted by author.

Comment: GROUP BY 1 groups by first field in SELECT statement - in this case - by author